# Is it possible to generate a report InTune Dependency Viewer?

Tags: powershell, dependencies, viewer, intune

I'm relatively new to creating apps and deploying them via InTune, but I need to view dependencies for an existing app to see what the order is for all InTune applications. The Dependency Viewer pretty much sucks in InTune, I have to know the last app deployed (which I do) and click to expand *each and every application* just to view the order instead of going to the existing app and seeing it's  prerequisites. This is tedious and time-consuming at best and wastes quite a bit of time. Does anyone know of a way to run a report or a query in PowerShell (or anything else, for that matter)?

Comment: To clarify, you want to see all dependent Win32 apps on a Win32 app? In other words, something that recursively walks through an entire dependency chain and shows you all the apps in said chain. Also, it's Intune, not InTune.

Comment: Check this link once https://www.petervanderwoude.nl/post/working-with-win32-app-dependencies/

Comment: @MusicMan Any update with the comment have you gone through that link

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT Hi! Yes, I read through the article, it describes how to set up dependencies and such but didn't have anything about generating a report or query, unfortunately.